# How can I have a plain text file open on startup? (lubuntu)

Tags: lubuntu, shortcuts, autostart

I've tried placing the file in my "autostart" folder but it's not loading properly it only opens featherpad.

I'm using LXQT version 0.17.0

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you've done, can you please be specific; the reference you made to *autostart* doesn't match the manual's description  https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/3/3.2/3.2.13/session_settings.html and what *folder* do you mean exactly?  (*my own Lubuntu system has many autostart directories for example & I can't know which you mean unless you're specific, including what you put it it*)   Release details are always helpful too.

Comment: /home/user_name/.config/autostart/ is where I place files in order to get them to auto start I wasn't following the manuals page ill check it out now, also sorry for spamming you with a hello message accidentally spam clicked the  "Add comment" button.

Comment: I also was going to ask why there were so many autostart folders I stumbled upon another and have no clue why there are more and what it can do.

Comment: I figured it out I wasn't sure how to use

Comment: @guiverc I figured it out I wasn't sure how to use Application Autostart before but now I do all I had to do was add the application "featherpad" to the command field then add the path of my plain text file, sorry for the headache thanks.

Comment: Please write an answer to your own question; in time you can accept it (*gaining +15 rep*.) and others may upvote it if good too (*more rep.*); regardless you're sharing information that may help other users which to me is worth way more than any *points.on.a.website*.  FYI: Providing release details is always helpful; you're likely using 22.04 (*jammy*) but that LXQt was also on another release for example (22.04 has backports which can upgrade LXQt too)

Comment: @guiverc wasn't aware I could answer my own question ill have to accept it tomorrow though since the system wont allow  me to do it today also I had no idea what LXQT was or that it was on another lubuntu release lol! This has been a fun experience  thanks again. :D

Comment: started looking over everything in terminal with cat /etc/os-release after a quick google search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the command field add your preferred editor you'd like to use first followed by the path to the file you want to open.

featherpad /this/is/my/file_

This worked for me my file opens up during startup every time in featherpad now.

I'm on Lubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)  LXQT version 0.17.0